# How to build GLEW from Ubuntu for Windows?

Tags: makefile, build, glew

I have a project that is intended to run on both "Ubuntu" and "Windows". Everything was fine until I was using only "glfw". But then I had to clear the screen, and under Ubuntu everything worked fine because the program uses OpenGL. However, when I tried to build it for Windows, the program couldn't find the function `glClear()`. I discovered that I could use "`glew`" and decided to include it. Here's where the problem arose: the libraries for Windows were compiled with a different compiler than "`x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc`", and the linker cannot find these libraries. It gives an empty value, which is usually the case when the library is incompatible with the linker.

I have tried several methods: copying the "`opengl32.dll`" from the Windows operating system and attempting to link it, but it was unsuccessful. I also tried setting the compiler options through "make" using the following command:

```
make LD=x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CXX=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ RC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-windres
```

but it didn't work either. It generated an object file with a lot of warnings. I also attempted to manually compile by specifying the path to the .h files using the command:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -c -I/media/sf_Ubuntu/glew-2.2.0/glew-2.2.0/include glew.c
```

, but it didn't help either. There were many warnings, and when I tried to create the .dll file, it resulted in an error.

How can I build the glew library with the **x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc** compiler to get two "libglew...lib" files and "libglew...dll" . Only x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc needs to be assembled.